# I Had 1 Problem ,Wan't to assign a unique random number between given range to each user

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel framework Wan't to assign a unique random number between given range to each user .
But My Code Dosen't Work .I am having user table I Wan't assign random user id to each user as secret santa. the range of number is between start id and end id of table

```html
 public function assign()
{
    $data=DB::table('emp')->get();
    $firstid=DB::table('emp')->get()->first()->id;
    $lastid=DB::table('emp')->get()->last()->id;
    // $affected = DB::table('users')
    //     ->where('email', $data->email)
    //     ->update(['secret_santa' => $secret]);

        $min=$firstid;
        $max=$lastid;
        $arr=range($min,$max);
        
        foreach ($data as $data) {
          $secret=$max--;  
          $affected = DB::table('emp')
          ->where('email', $data->email)
          ->update(['secret_santa' => $secret]);
    }
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Throws an error? Gives a different result than you expect? Please try to give a sample of your expected result.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php in order to select a random value from $arr

Comment: want to assign random user from same table as secret santa

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
public function assign()
{
    $ids = DB::table('emp')->pluck('id');
    $randomList = $ids->all();

    $ids->each(function ($id) use ($randomList)
    {
        // pick a random id different from the current id
        $randomKey = 0;
        $secret = $id;
        do {
            $randomKey = array_rand($randomList);
            $secret = $randomList[$randomKey];
        } while ($secret === $id);

        // omit the picked id from the list
        array_splice($randomList, $randomKey, 1)

        // update the record of the current id with the picked random secret
        DB::table('emp')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->update(['secret_santa' => $secret]);
    });

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks For Sharing Solution.But Didn't get unique id for each user as secret santa.Same Id Repeated for 2-3 users. i need unique id per user.